# Где лучше хранить фотографии сделанные из приложения на камеру

Tags: android

Есть приложение, в котором есть `ImageView`. Нажав на него пользователь либо делает фото на камеру либо выбирает из галереи и должен сохранить куда-то.

Куда лучше сохранять такие изображения? В Приватном хранилище приложения или можно создать какую-то папку в памяти телефона и туда сохранять? В чем разница?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: Сперва обдумайте, а надо ли вообще делать дубликаты. Хранилища не резиновые, знаете ли...

Comment: Пользователь может удалить фотографию из галереи, а мне нужно, чтобы если даже фотографию удалили из галереи, картинка все равно была доступна в приложении.

Comment: в отдельной папке на карте памяти/общей памяти телефона

Comment: Спасибо, pavlofff. А можете подсказать ресурс, где можно прочитать о том как сохранять изображения в такую отдельную папку?

Comment: подскажу один известный ресурс, где можно [о многом почитать](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=android%20save%20bitmap%20to%20storage&lr=62&clid=2041722)